# what happens when I write a function using tensorflow ops

Tags: python, tensorflow

I write a function using tensorflow ops. I know the fact when I run the function, it will add many ops to the graph. But I am confused with how to get access of these ops.

for example:

```
def assign_weights():
    with tf.name_scope('zheng'):
        v = tf.Variable(0, 'v', dtype=tf.float32)
        b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=())
        z = tf.assign(v, b)
    return z, b
```

I can use `feed_dict` to pass `a` value to `b`, only if I set `b` as a return value. Otherwise, there is no way to access `b`. If we want to access many ops in the function scope, we should set many return values. This is very ugly.

I want to know what happens under the hood when I run functions using tensorflow and how to get access of the ops in the function scope.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, it's true that to access an op (or tensor) we need some reference to it. IMHO, one standard workaround is to build your graph in a class and make certain tensors attributes of the class and access them through the object.

Alternatively, if you're more inclined to the functional approach, a better way than returning all relevant ops and tensors separately would be to return a dict (or namedtuple).

Additionally, there are also specialized functions that return ops by name: e.g. [`get_operation_by_name`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_operation_by_name).

As an aside to this question, you might also want to try out [eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager), which is imperative.

Answer (score 0):

3 things happen when you use op function:

- create and add a compute node to default graph
- set your input as the node input tensor
- set node output tensor as return value

for example, `a = tf.add(b, c, name='add')`,

- add a node with op `Add` to default graph, with name 'add'
- set b and c as node input tensor
- set node output, with name 'add:0', to a

So you can access nodes via `sess.graph`, there are many functions to access nodes, say, get_operation_by_name.

Also, you can operate the graph via `sess.graph_def`, which is serialized graph with protobuf, you can find the protobuf definition in the tensorflow source code, `tensorflow/core/framework`, some .proto files there.